# Dot character cancels completion in Sublime Text plugin

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I'm working on a Sublime Text 3 plugin, which contains a number of completions for the standard library. Some of these functions (e.g. `io.open( filename, mode )`) contain the dot character (".").

The problem is, Sublime Text cancels the completion dialog when a "." is typed (word boundary).

To get around this, I've tried using underscores instead of dots in the triggers:

```
{"trigger": "io_open( filename, mode )", "contents": "io.open( ${1:filename}, ${2:mode} )"}
```

However, this doesn't work very well at all. If the user tries to type in `io.open` instead of `io_open`, Sublime restarts the completion at the dot, and they end up with  `io.io.open`.

Is there any way around this? Having the dot character as word boundary is useful for selecting text, so I'd like to keep that if it is possible.

Comment: Try posting on the SublimeText [plugin-development](https://forum.sublimetext.com/c/plugin-development) forum.

Comment: @mattst Thanks, I'll give that a go.